# Using pd.to_numeric to convert number "０１８９８" in Chinese code to 1898 not working

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, character-encoding

I tried to get the stock codes from a Chinese news extracted from the web site 'http://www.etnet.com.hk/www/tc/news/categorized_news_list.php?page=1&category=result'. However, the following code does not work. Numbers like `０１８９８`  are in Chinese code format and cannot convert to 1898 using `pd.to_numeric`.

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

base_url = "http://www.etnet.com.hk/www/tc/news/categorized_news_list.php?page=1&category=result"
result = requests.get(base_url)
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')

df = pd.DataFrame()

news = []
for a_tag in soup.find_all('p'):
    news.append(a_tag.text)
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(news, columns=['News']))
df['num'] = df['News'].str.extract('\（(\d+)\）')  
df["stock_num"] = pd.to_numeric(df["num"], errors="coerce").fillna(0).astype("int64")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's `int` can handle non-ASCII Unicode digits, so this works:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

base_url = "http://www.etnet.com.hk/www/tc/news/categorized_news_list.php?page=1&category=result"
result = requests.get(base_url)
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')

df = pd.DataFrame()

news = []
for a_tag in soup.find_all('p'):
    news.append(a_tag.text)
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(news, columns=['News']))

def to_int(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return 0

df['num'] = df['News'].str.extract('\（(\d+)\）')  
df["stock_num"] = df["num"].apply(to_int).astype("int64")
print(df)
```

```
                                                  News    num  stock_num
0                                     21/01/2020 09:31    NaN          0
1                       【企業盈警】中彩網通（８０７１）料去年錄虧損，或中止虧損業務   ８０７１       8071
2    　　《經濟通通訊社２１日專訊》中彩網通（０８０７１）預期去年第四季度的收入將顯著下降，而截至...  ０８０７１       8071
3                                     21/01/2020 09:28    NaN          0
4                       《業績變臉》再多１５家Ａ股公司計提減值準備，減值近３百億人幣    NaN          0
..                                                 ...    ...        ...
894                                              強積金資訊    NaN          0
895                                             MPF小字典    NaN          0
896                                             退休金計算機    NaN          0
897                                                       NaN          0
898                                              我的MPF    NaN          0

[899 rows x 3 columns]
```